# How to access class external to package in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

Summary: I'm looking for some guidance on accessing classes in an external package.

Here's the specifics:

1. I have installed the :graph package with Quicklisp, found here: https://github.com/eschulte/graph
2. The first example in the docs is this:

```
(defvar *graph* (populate (make-instance 'graph)
                  :nodes '(a b c d e f g)
                  :edges-w-values '(((a b) . 3)
                                    ((b d) . 1)
                                    ((b c) . 2)
                                    ((c e) . 1)
                                    ((d e) . 2)
                                    ((e f) . 3))))
```

3. I have included :graph as a dependency in my package (:hsm-new). So to access the "populate" function I do `(defvar *graph* (graph:populate...`
4. How do I access the `'graph` class in the first line?

Thank you, please forgive someone new to CLOS and relatively new to packages.

Comment: This is a just a normal symbol. Just as you write `graph:populate` to call the function, you need to write `(make-instance graph:graph)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Doing this throws the error "The variable GRAPH/GRAPH:GRAPH is unbound."

Comment: `(make-instance 'graph:graph)`-> symbols need to be quoted

Comment: Aha! Thanks so much for the swift help, squad! You're the best.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: 'graph:graph (quote the package then the data).